# R Loop over IDs

Tags: r, rapidminer, tidytext

I'd like to run pairwise_count in a loop and my input looks like the table in the image. Each ID stands for a text and the rows contains the sentences of the text. 
My idea of a for loop doesn't work. Has someone maybe an idea, how that loop could run?

[This is my input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlF56.png)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(widyr)

rm_main = function(data)
{
 korpus <- data_frame(id =data$id, text = data$text)

 print(korpus)

 woerter <- korpus %>%
 unnest_tokens(word, text)%>%
 group_by(id)%>%
 count(word)
 print(woerter)
woerter <- as.data.frame(woerter)

cooccurre <- korpus %>%
 for( i in unique(id))
 {
  unnest_tokens(word, text)%>%
  pairwise_count(word, i)
 }
 print(cooccurre)
 cooccurre <- as.data.frame(cooccurre)

 return(list(woerter, cooccurre)) 
 }
```

My script input (data) looks like this table:

```
id  text    Title   query_key
1.0 ? Vier Lehrer haben geklagt, am Mittwoch verhandelt das Bundesverfassungsgericht.   SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten   sentences
1.0 . Jobwechsel zur Konkurrenz: So lässt sich eine Bewerbung geheim halten Falscher Raketenalarm auf Hawaii: Auch diese Job-Pannen sorgten für Chaos Missbrauchsskandal im US-Turnen Ein schrecklicher Ort Auch Superstar Simone Biles war Opfer im Missbrauchsskandal des US-Kunstturnens.    SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten   sentences
1.0 . Grundsteuer vor dem Verfassungsgericht Unter jedem Dach droht ein Ach Seit Jahrzehnten bekommt die Politik keine Reform der völlig veralteten Grundsteuer hin.    SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten   sentences
1.0 . Für Hausbesitzer und Mieter könnte das massive Steuererhöhungen bedeuten. SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten   sentences
1.0 . Nun zeigt sich: Die Ergebnisse dieser wissenschaftlichen Methode werden immer ungenauer.  SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten   sentences
2.0 . Und einer ist immer hellgrün. Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE sentences
2.0 . Zu Schuljahresbeginn werden in Baden-Württemberg an staatlichen und privaten Schulen von den Klassenlehrern Versicherungspolicen an die Schüler verteilt. Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE sentences
2.0 . Die einen sind hellgrün, die anderen rosa.    Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE sentences
2.0 . Die Versicherung kostet nicht viel, nur einen Euro pro Schuljahr. Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE sentences
2.0 . Wie der Mutter aus Esslingen geht es Hunderttausenden Eltern in Baden-Württemberg.    Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE sentences
3.0 ? Hier finden Sie mehr Informationen .  Bogner: Wolfgang Reitzle wird Aufsichtsratschef - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
3.0 . Sie haben einen anderen Browser?  Bogner: Wolfgang Reitzle wird Aufsichtsratschef - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
3.0 . Nun besetzt das Münchner Modeunternehmen auch seinen Aufsichtsrat neu.    Bogner: Wolfgang Reitzle wird Aufsichtsratschef - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
3.0 . Mittwoch, 17. Bogner: Wolfgang Reitzle wird Aufsichtsratschef - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
3.0 . An die Spitze des Gremiums hat Firmeninhaber Willy Bogner den Aufsichtsratsvorsitzenden des Industriegase-Konzerns Linde, Wolfgang Reitzle, berufen.  Bogner: Wolfgang Reitzle wird Aufsichtsratschef - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
3.0 . Sie haben einen anderen Browser?  Bogner: Wolfgang Reitzle wird Aufsichtsratschef - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
4.0 . Da liegt es für die Koalitionssondierer nahe, die Steuern kräftig zu senken.  CDU, CSU und SPD: Vorsicht vor zu großzügigen Steuergeschenken! - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
4.0 . Ein Kommentar von Stefan Kaiser Jahrgang 1976.    CDU, CSU und SPD: Vorsicht vor zu großzügigen Steuergeschenken! - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
4.0 . Ausbildung an der Berliner Journalisten-Schule.   CDU, CSU und SPD: Vorsicht vor zu großzügigen Steuergeschenken! - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
4.0 . Seit Juni 2011 Redakteur im Wirtschaftsressort von SPIEGEL ONLINE, seit Mai 2014 Reporter.    CDU, CSU und SPD: Vorsicht vor zu großzügigen Steuergeschenken! - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
4.0 . Mehr Artikel von Stefan Kaiser Donnerstag, 11.    CDU, CSU und SPD: Vorsicht vor zu großzügigen Steuergeschenken! - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
5.0 . Die meisten Herzerkrankungen sind vermeidbar - und zwar ganz leicht.  thema-herz-gesundheit -Video - SPIEGEL ONLINE   sentences
5.0 . SPIEGEL TV Thema: Wie hilfreich sind Diäten?  thema-herz-gesundheit -Video - SPIEGEL ONLINE   sentences
5.0 ? Eingestürztes Kölner Stadtarchiv: Prozess versucht Schuldfrage zu klären 'Drecksloch'-Affäre um Donald Trump: US-Senator Booker platzt der Kragen Der Kampf um die Große Koalition in NRW: 'Mund-zu-Mund-Beatmung der Parteispitze' Trump-Satirevideo: Ein 'Shithole' schlägt zurück Rekordwinter in den USA: Eisige Landschaften Himmelskörper: Meteor rast über Michigan hinweg Britisches Unterhaus: Abgeordneter verschläft Brexit-Debatte Risse in Tribüne: Porto-Fans stürmen den Platz Ein Jahr Trump: Die Gewinner im Trump-Staat Texas Mexiko: Längste Unterwasserhöhle der Welt entdeckt Slacklining in Nazaré: Balanceakt vor Riesenwellen thema-herz-gesundheit -Video - SPIEGEL ONLINE 09.   thema-herz-gesundheit -Video - SPIEGEL ONLINE   sentences
5.0 . Die meisten Herzerkrankungen sind vermeidbar - und zwar ganz leicht.  thema-herz-gesundheit -Video - SPIEGEL ONLINE   sentences
5.0 . SPIEGEL TV Thema: Wie hilfreich sind Diäten?  thema-herz-gesundheit -Video - SPIEGEL ONLINE   sentences
6.0 . Zum Beispiel durch üppige Suppen und Eintöpfe wie den spanischen Cocido de Garbanzos. Rezept für spanischen Eintopf: Cocido de Garbanzos - SPIEGEL ONLINE sentences
6.0 . Jahrgang 1960, lebt in Hamburg und kocht länger, als er für Geld schreibt: Seit seinem 16.    Rezept für spanischen Eintopf: Cocido de Garbanzos - SPIEGEL ONLINE sentences
6.0 . Als furchtloser Esser mag der hauptberufliche Musikkritiker im Grunde alles, solange es mit Liebe und Verstand aus frischen Zutaten gekocht wird. Rezept für spanischen Eintopf: Cocido de Garbanzos - SPIEGEL ONLINE sentences
6.0 . Wo man hinkommt, gibt es jedenfalls erst mal einen Teller Suppe: In Polen einen Bigosch mit Sauerkraut, Pilzen und allerlei Schweinernem; weiter östlich in der Ukraine oder Russland sind es die Eintöpfe auf der Basis von Roten Beten, Kohl oder Salzgurken - Borschtsch, Schtschi und Soljanka.   Rezept für spanischen Eintopf: Cocido de Garbanzos - SPIEGEL ONLINE sentences
6.0 . Die Cajun-Küche Louisianas ist erfüllt vom Schmackofatzgeruch des Jambalaya mit Huhn und Garnelen, in Belgien blubbert derweil ein wallonischer Hochepot, in den Alpen von Bayern bis Slowenien liebt man den Ritschert mit Rauchfleisch und sättigenden Graupen und Hülsenfrüchten, während beim Irish Stew noch der älteste und ansonsten unessbare Hammel durch stundenlanges Kochen halbwegs kaubar wird. Rezept für spanischen Eintopf: Cocido de Garbanzos - SPIEGEL ONLINE sentences
416.0   . Wie viele andere Ackerwildkräuter wird es durch die intensivere landwirtschaftliche Nutzung verdrängt.    Pflanzenatlas: Wo Farne und Kräuter in Deutschland sprießen - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
416.0   . Das Inventar der Pflanzenverbreitung ist laut BfN nicht nur als Druckwerk, sondern auch als Datenbank wichtig.    Pflanzenatlas: Wo Farne und Kräuter in Deutschland sprießen - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
416.0   . Tausende meist ehrenamtliche Pflanzenexperten erfassten die Daten in mehrjähriger Kartierungsarbeit in der Natur und in Siedlungsgebieten.    Pflanzenatlas: Wo Farne und Kräuter in Deutschland sprießen - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
416.0   . Sie seien aufgrund ihrer Strukturvielfalt sehr artenreich, hätten aber auch einen sehr hohen Anteil pflanzlicher Neueinwanderer, sagte Jessel.    Pflanzenatlas: Wo Farne und Kräuter in Deutschland sprießen - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
416.0   . Wie heißt du denn, meine Schöne?  Pflanzenatlas: Wo Farne und Kräuter in Deutschland sprießen - SPIEGEL ONLINE    sentences
1368.0  . Kann es eine bessere Empfehlung für das Amt des bayerischen Ministerpräsidenten geben?    CSU-Machtkampf: Markus Söder ist der beste Nachfolger Horst Seehofers - SPIEGEL ONLINE  sentences
1368.0  . Nach dem Mauerfall für den SPIEGEL in Leipzig, dann in Berlin und New York, wo er vier Jahre als Wirtschaftskorrespondent arbeitete; seit 2005, pünktlich zum langen Abschied von Rot-Grün, wieder in Berlin. CSU-Machtkampf: Markus Söder ist der beste Nachfolger Horst Seehofers - SPIEGEL ONLINE  sentences
1368.0  . Ich bin froh, dass es die CSU gibt.   CSU-Machtkampf: Markus Söder ist der beste Nachfolger Horst Seehofers - SPIEGEL ONLINE  sentences
1368.0  ? Gegen die CSU sind sogar die Grünen, die sich auf ihre Unangepasstheit mächtig was einbilden, ein anämischer Verein.  CSU-Machtkampf: Markus Söder ist der beste Nachfolger Horst Seehofers - SPIEGEL ONLINE  sentences
1368.0  . Es ist dann die Aufgabe der Kollegen vor Ort, also von Leuten wie mir, die neuesten Entwicklungen im bayerischen Erbfolgekrieg darzulegen.    CSU-Machtkampf: Markus Söder ist der beste Nachfolger Horst Seehofers - SPIEGEL ONLINE  sentences
2014.0  . So landet die sizilianische Naturlandzitrone unerkannt auch bei Aldi. Bio oder regional: Welche Lebensmittel sind nachhaltiger? - SPIEGEL ONLINE  sentences
2014.0  ? Muss so billiges Gemüse nicht unter ähnlich industriellen Bedingungen erzeugt werden wie konventionelle Massenware?   Bio oder regional: Welche Lebensmittel sind nachhaltiger? - SPIEGEL ONLINE  sentences
2014.0  ? Seit Jahren stagniert der Anteil ökologischer Anbauflächen in Deutschland trotz boomender Nachfrage nach Biobst und -Gemüse.  Bio oder regional: Welche Lebensmittel sind nachhaltiger? - SPIEGEL ONLINE  sentences
2014.0  . Immer häufiger kommt das Gemüse auch aus Weltregionen, in denen es natürlicherweise gar nicht wächst: Kartoffeln aus Wüstenländern wie Ägypten oder Israel, Gurken vom Rand der Sahara, Tomaten aus Gewächshäusern an der trockenen Südküste Spaniens.    Bio oder regional: Welche Lebensmittel sind nachhaltiger? - SPIEGEL ONLINE  sentences
```

regards

Tobias

Comment: Please don't post images of your data! Read [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: @kath sorry about that, I edit the Code. Maybe you have a solution for my problem.

Comment: I believe that we will need to fix you up with something involving map() but unfortunately there is not enough information here for us to help you. If you can post a small example data set (as described in the post about reproducible examples) then we can help you get started.

Comment: Hi Julia, I added some lines of my input data. For each ID I'd like to count the co-occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I worked a bit on my script and now it looks like this:

```
library(loopr)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(stringr)
library(widyr)
library(tidytext)

input <- read.csv(file ="/home/knecht/Script input1.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
print(input)

example <- data_frame(id =input$id, text = input$text)
print(example)

test <- example %>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(linenumber = row_number(),
         article = cumsum(str_detect(text, regex("^Artikel [\\divxlc]", ignore_case = TRUE))))%>%
  ungroup()
print(test)

for(i in unique(id)){
wortpaar <- test%>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)%>%
  pairwise_count(word, id)
}

print(wortpaar)
```

Is it possible to group the co-occurrences for each id like: id, item1, item2, n ?

This is a part of the content of my input file:

```
    Title,query_key,text,id
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Wegen dessen Steuerreform muss das Unternehmen in den USA wohl 38 Milliarden Dollar zahlen.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Kabel, DSL, Mobilnetz: Internet viel langsamer als versprochen Absturz der Digitalwährung: Bitcoin fällt unter 10.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,"? Sprengfotograf: Jedes Bild ein Knaller The Blight House: Trump's Presidency Sinks Below Rock Bottom FC Barcelona Star Lionel Messi: Tax Troubles, an Audit and a 100-Million-Euro Contract Pollution Quiz: Where the Air Is Dirtiest SPD vor Parteitag Das große Zählen und Zittern Martin Schulz auf GroKo-Tour: Nach NRW wirbt der SPD-Chef auch in Bayern für die Große Koalition.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Und am Ende?,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Von Max Holscher und Christian Teevs mehr.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Eine Frage dürfte dabei besonders spannend werden - welche Gremien wird die AfD leiten?,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Wen es wie hart trifft - und wie Sie selbst nachmessen können.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,"? Erschießen, vergiften, aushungern: Jäger sollen großflächig Wildschweine töten, damit sich die Afrikanische Schweinepest nicht nach Deutschland ausbreitet.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Von Johanna Sagmeister mehr.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Außerdem: die Top-News, Trump im Reality-Check und Harald Schmidt im Schnee-Stau.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". SPIEGEL DAILY, täglich um 17 Uhr.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Die hatte Präsident Trump im 'Shithole'-Skandal verteidigt.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Neue Regeln auf YouTube Für One-Hit-Wonder gibt's kein Geld mehr Es wird schwerer, auf YouTube Geld zu verdienen: Unter dem Druck der Werbebranche ändert Google seine Regeln.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Von Markus Böhm mehr.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Jetzt stehen fünf Personen vor Gericht: Wie viel Schuld tragen sie an dem Unglück?,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Das sagen Betroffene.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,"? Vordenker der Neuen Rechten Die Offenbarung des Jean Raspail 1973 veröffentlichte ein Franzose einen Zukunftsroman, der von einem Flüchtlingsansturm handelt, einem Schiffsunglück und einem Papst namens Benedikt.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Von Alexander Smoltczyk mehr.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Altkanzler-Witwe Maike Kohl-Richter 'Ich gelte als Monster' Nach dem Tod von Helmut Kohl eskalierte der Streit zwischen den Hinterbliebenen des Altkanzlers.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Ihre Vorwürfe klingen bitter.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Im letzten Spiel der Vorrunde gab es gegen Mazedonien erneut ein Unentschieden.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Nach Remis gegen Deutschland: Handball-Verband weist Einspruch Sloweniens ab Angelique Kerber bei Australian Open Mehr Finesse dank Fissette Nach einem beispiellosen Absturz in der Weltrangliste hat Angelique Kerber zu alter Stärke zurückgefunden.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Von Bastian Midasch mehr.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. US-Konkurrentin Tonya Harding räumte später Mitschuld ein und hofft nun auf Vergebung - dank Hollywood.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Fotostrecke: Die Prinzessin und die Eishexe Basketball brutal: 'The Punch' - fast zu Tode geprügelt Berlin Fashion Week Sieht jut aus Fashion Week in Berlin.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Von Philipp Löwe mehr.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Hier ist das Video.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Produkttest Große Schnauze, nichts dahinter Die Selbstoptimierung kennt keine Grenzen: Ein Mundstück verspricht ein strafferes, schmaleres Gesicht bereits nach kurzem Tragen.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Produkttest: Straff mit Stoffmaske - geht das?,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Hier können Sie einen Blick in die Luxusvilla werfen.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Sascha Lobo: der Debatten-Podcast #21.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Britisches Unterhaus Abgeordneter verschläft Brexit-Debatte Missbrauchsskandal im US-Turnen: Opfer sagen gegen Teamarzt Nassar aus Trump-Satirevideo: Ein 'Shithole' schlägt zurück Slacklining in Nazaré: Balanceakt vor (und in) Riesenwellen Ein Jahr Trump: Die Gewinner im Trump-Staat Texas Jusos gegen Schulz: 'Nie, nie, nie wieder GroKo!",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Vielleicht sollte sie sich auf eine ihrer Grundideen besinnen: die Folgen der Maschine gesellschaftlich zu bewältigen.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Das verkündet das Model auf Instagram - und berichtet von ihren Gründen.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Neuzugang im Londoner Zoo Ein Okapi namens Meghan Meghan ist bildhübsch, topfit und wurde innerhalb kürzester Zeit zum Star.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Wäre da nicht das gestreifte Hinterteil.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Prozess in Dresden: Bundesanwaltschaft fordert lange Haftstrafen für 'Gruppe Freital' Missbrauchsfall bei Freiburg: 'Die Richter haben sich überschätzt' Rekordwinter in den USA: Eisige Landschaften Himmelskörper: Meteor rast über Michigan hinweg Gegenbilder: Neueste Werke des Künstlers Thomas Demand Tarnnamen von Ex-Agent Werner Mauss = Richard Nelson = Claus Möllner Seit mehr als 30 Jahren arbeitet Werner Mauss nicht mehr als Geheimagent für das Bundeskriminalamt.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". GroKo-Debatte in der SPD Die Vorzeige-Demokraten Man kann sich über die SPD prima lustig machen in diesen Tagen: Seht, wie sie sich wieder zerlegen!",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Ein Kommentar von Florian Gathmann mehr.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Vor dem Oberlandesgericht Düsseldorf äußert ein Gutachter Zweifel am Vorgehen der Behörde.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Finanzindustrie EU-Bürgerbeauftragte fordert Draghis Austritt aus Lobby-Forum Zwischen Finanzindustrie und Notenbank soll eine klare Trennung her.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Zeitungsbericht: Britische Supermärkte produzieren eine Million Tonnen Plastikmüll jährlich Sportmodefirma: Reitzle wird Aufsichtsratschef bei Bogner Pyeongchang 2018 Nord- und Südkorea stellen gemeinsames Team für Olympia Südkorea hat bestätigt, dass Nordkorea der Bildung einer gemeinsamen Damen-Eishockeymannschaft zustimmt.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Missbrauchsskandal im US-Turnen Opfer sagen unter Tränen gegen Nassar aus Ein schwerer Tag für die Opfer: Vor Gericht haben Turnerinnen unter Tränen ausgesagt, die von dem Teamarzt Larry Nassar missbraucht worden sind.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Abstimmung: EU-Parlament will Elektrofischerei weiter einschränken Pumpspeicher: Tüftler machen Gefällekraftwerk ohne Gefälle möglich Wachsende Population: Wölfin 'Naya' aus Mecklenburg läuft bis nach Brüssel '4 Blocks' Rapper Gzuz ist bei der zweiten Staffel dabei Ende Januar ist Drehstart, nun werden erste Details zur zweiten Staffel der gefeierten deutschen Gangster-Serie '4 Blocks' bekannt.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Alec Baldwin über Kritik an Woody Allen 'Unfair und traurig' Immer mehr Schauspieler wenden sich wegen des Vorwurfs des Kindesmissbrauchs von Woody Allen ab.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Fernsehjahr 2017: 'Babylon Berlin', 'Hindafing' und '4 Blocks' für Grimme-Preis nominiert Regisseur von 'Police Academy': Hugh Wilson ist tot Studenten im Heidelberger Nachtleben Bloß keinen 'warmen Erpel' trinken Spätestens um 4 Uhr morgens ist in Heidelberg Schluss mit Party: Es gilt eine strenge Sperrstunde.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Ost-West-Austausch Warum Schüler aus NRW nach Sachsen fahren - und umgekehrt Ist fast 30 Jahre nach der Wende noch ein Schüleraustausch zwischen Ost- und Westdeutschland nötig?,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Manche Schulen halten trotzdem daran fest.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Baden-Württemberg: Das Versicherungsgeschäft mit den Schülern Ostbeauftragte der Bundesregierung: Gleicke lehnt Ost-West-Schüleraustausch ab Für US-Markt Chinesischer Konzern nennt Automarke 'Trumpchi' um Ein chinesischer Konzern will eine Automarke auf den US-Markt bringen.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Malaysia: Yabba, dabba, doo - der Sultan fährt das Auto von Fred Feuerstein Winfried Kretschmann: Ein Ministerpräsident redet übers Blech Autogramm Ford Ecosport: Gut durchgeliftet Sterberisiko Jeder Vierte stirbt an einer Herzkrankheit Die größten Gefahren für das Leben drohen den Deutschen durch Infarkte, Organschwächen und koronare Herzkrankheiten.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Tech-Neuheiten in Bildern: 50 Gadgets von der CES 2018 Strafbare Inhalte: Staatssekretär Kelber warnt soziale Netzwerke Horrormeister John Carpenter zum 70.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Jetzt wird der Meister des Horrors 70 Jahre alt.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Gamal Abdel Nasser Der letzte Pharao Gamal Abdel Nasser wäre heute 100 Jahre alt geworden.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Honeckers letzte Reise ins Exil: Der Passagier auf Platz 13A Selbsttötung von Ramón Sampedro: Das Recht zu sterben Befristete Verträge rechtens Torwart Heinz Müller verliert Prozess vor Bundesarbeitsgericht Fußballprofis verdienen oft Millionen und sind doch prekär beschäftigt, mit Fristverträgen.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Bundesverfassungsgericht Kippt das Streikverbot für Lehrer?,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. So steht es im Grundgesetz.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,"? Vier Lehrer haben geklagt, am Mittwoch verhandelt das Bundesverfassungsgericht.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Jobwechsel zur Konkurrenz: So lässt sich eine Bewerbung geheim halten Falscher Raketenalarm auf Hawaii: Auch diese Job-Pannen sorgten für Chaos Missbrauchsskandal im US-Turnen Ein schrecklicher Ort Auch Superstar Simone Biles war Opfer im Missbrauchsskandal des US-Kunstturnens.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Grundsteuer vor dem Verfassungsgericht Unter jedem Dach droht ein Ach Seit Jahrzehnten bekommt die Politik keine Reform der völlig veralteten Grundsteuer hin.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Für Hausbesitzer und Mieter könnte das massive Steuererhöhungen bedeuten.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Nun zeigt sich: Die Ergebnisse dieser wissenschaftlichen Methode werden immer ungenauer.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Wie reagiert man am besten?,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Viele der Looks werden Sie bald in den Schaufenstern der Geschäfte sehen.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Von Haute Couture zur Haute Cuisine: Schmeckt's Schwein besser, wenn Gucci kocht?",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Dafür muss er manchmal schummeln.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Vielleicht sollte sie sich auf eine ihrer Grundideen besinnen: die Folgen der Maschine gesellschaftlich zu bewältigen.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Die IT-Sicherheitsfirma Kaspersky Lab hat eine solche Malware nun entdeckt.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Tech-Neuheiten in Bildern: 50 Gadgets von der CES 2018 Strafbare Inhalte: Staatssekretär Kelber warnt soziale Netzwerke Horrormeister John Carpenter zum 70.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". Mode: Diese Jogginghosen wollen wir jetzt sofort anziehen Geheimnisse eines Kochs: 'Es wird gesoffen, gebrüllt, gekokst' Irans Spione in Deutschland Im Auftrag der Mullahs Wie ein Geheimdienst-General in Teheran sein internationales Agenten-Netzwerk steuert - und was seine Leute in der Bundesrepublik treiben.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,". SPIEGEL DAILY, täglich um 17 Uhr.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,? Sudoku: Der Logik-Klassiker für jeden Tag Kenken: Das Sudoku mit plus und mal Zu den Cartoons des Monats Steinhoff: Wie die US-Bankelite sich die Finger an Steinhoff verbrannte Alternativen zur 'Sardinenbüchse' S-Klasse: Diese Autos müssten selbst für Winfried Kretschmann groß genug sein Bitcoin stürzt Richtung 9000 Dollar: Krypto Absturz geht weiter Bitte deaktivieren Sie Ihren Adblocker!,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Wählen Sie die Option „Deaktivieren auf: spiegel.,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Vielen Dank!,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,"? Bitte prüfen Sie, ob Sie ähnliche Erweiterungen, Do-not-Track-Funktionen oder den Inkognito-Modus aktiviert haben, die ebenfalls Werbung unterdrücken.",1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,? Hier finden Sie mehr Informationen .,1.0
SPIEGEL ONLINE - Aktuelle Nachrichten,sentences,. Sie haben einen anderen Browser?,1.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Verbraucherschützer sind alarmiert.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Sie kannte das schon.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Und einer ist immer hellgrün.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Zu Schuljahresbeginn werden in Baden-Württemberg an staatlichen und privaten Schulen von den Klassenlehrern Versicherungspolicen an die Schüler verteilt.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Die einen sind hellgrün, die anderen rosa.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Die Versicherung kostet nicht viel, nur einen Euro pro Schuljahr.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Wie der Mutter aus Esslingen geht es Hunderttausenden Eltern in Baden-Württemberg.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Manche füllen auch eine der Zusatzversicherungen aus für Garderobe (ein Euro), Fahrrad (sechs Euro), Musikinstrumente (sechs Euro) und für Internatsschüler (sechs bis sieben Euro).",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. In der Regel zahlt die gesetzliche Versicherung Dabei ist eine Schülerzusatzversicherung nach Ansichten von Branchenkennern kaum notwendig.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Und die meisten Familien haben auch schon Haftpflichtversicherungen.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Bei den 167.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Die kennen sie, weil sie dort einen Euro einzahlen müssen.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Die Schule sollte seiner Ansicht nach ein geschützter und werbefreier Ort sein: 'Dort sollten keine solchen Geschäfte stattfinden.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,"? Google, Lego, Apple im Klassenraum: Die wollen doch nur helfen - oder?",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Sie widerspreche einer Verwaltungsvorschrift vom September 2002 zur 'Werbung für wirtschaftliche, politische, weltanschauliche und sonstige Interessen' an baden-württembergischen Schulen, so Breun-Goerke.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. In anderen Bundesländern kennt man solche Geschäfte in Schulen nicht.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Dabei ist es das gar nicht', erklärt Peter Grieble von der Verbraucherzentrale Baden-Württemberg.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Das Angebot sei lückenhaft und decke nur einen sehr kleinen Ausschnitt ab.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Vorwürfe, die die Versicherer zurückweisen.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Er hatte sich bei seinem Schulleiter darüber beschwert, auch noch als Versicherungsmakler agieren zu müssen.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Notfalls müsse man bei den Schülern, die keine Police abgeben wollten, eben Druck machen.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Verbraucherschützer kritisieren solche Praktiken schon lange.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Kritisch sehen die Verbraucherschützer auch, dass es keinerlei Beratung beim Verkauf der Versicherungen gebe.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Die 'Mitwirkung der Lehrkräfte', sekundiert auch das Ministerium, falle 'kaum ins Gewicht'.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Sie müssen lediglich die Policen an die Schulen senden.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Die Schulverwaltungen überweisen die Beiträge an die Konzerne.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Bei einem bis acht Euro Einnahmen pro Schüler kämen Millionen für den Versicherer zusammen, ist sich Ralph Audörsch sicher.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Er ist in den Schulen seiner drei Kinder im Alter zwischen 8 und 18 Jahren Elternvertreter und wettert im Internet gegen die Verträge.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Während die WGV auch hierzu die Auskunft verweigert, gibt die BGV an, man bearbeite pro Schuljahr 'mehrere tausend Schadensfälle'.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Werbeaktion im Unterricht: Zweitklässler singen während der Schulzeit bei Rewe (22.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Diskutieren Sie über diesen Artikel ''Denen wurde gesagt: Wenn ihr da nicht dabei seid, dann dürft ihr zu keinem Ausflug mehr mitfahren', erzählt Juliane S.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Aber auch [.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Aber auch das der Eltern, die ganz kritiklos unterschreiben.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Sicher kann man sich über die Sinnhaftigkeit einer zusätzlichen Unfallversicherung bei Vorhandensein der gesetzlichen Unfallversicherung [.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Sicher kann man sich über die Sinnhaftigkeit einer zusätzlichen Unfallversicherung bei Vorhandensein der gesetzlichen Unfallversicherung streiten bzw.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Aber alleine die Instrumentenversicherung (6,- EUR pro Jahr) ist für alle Schüler sinnvoll, die ein Instrument mit zur Schule bringen, und das ist bei einer Vielzahl der Schüler der Fall.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Ich selber kenne zahlreiche Fälle, in denen Schäden wie Instrumentenreparatur oder Garderobenklau unbürokratisch und kulant geregelt wurden.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Die Behauptung des Versicherungsagenten, es hätte keine einzige Regulierung gegegen, ist schlichtweg Blödsinn.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Die reine Information, dass es solche Zusatzversicherungen gibt, ist aber m.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Zitat: Die Konzerne halten dagegen, das sei wegen der Geringfügigkeit der Police von einem Euro gar nicht notwendig.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Die 'Mitwirkung der Lehrkräfte', sekundiert auch das Ministerium, falle 'kaum ins Gewicht'.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Meiner Meinung nach ist die Mitwirkung der Lehrkräfte geradezu essentiell: wer sonst als die Lehrer kennt die Schüler, kann diese überzeugen, verfügt zudem noch über die Adressen dieser Zielgruppen und ist bereit, den ersten Schritt in dieser Akquise zu übernehmen?",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Das dadurch gewonnene Adress- und Datenmaterial ist das eigentliche 'Gold' für die Versicherer.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Eine Beratung ist nicht notwendig?,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Ansonsten ist eine Beratung über Art und Umfang der [.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Ansonsten ist eine Beratung über Art und Umfang der Versicherung Pflicht.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Im schlimmsten Fall kündigt der Kunde eine vorhandene besser ausgestatte Versicherung (oder schließt sie gar nicht ab), weil er glaubt, das eine ausreichende Versicherung besteht.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Makler, Versicherungsberater, Vermittler werden zu umfangreicher Dokumentation gezwungen und haften für die Richtigkeit Ihrer Empfehlung und hier werden Versicherungsverträge einfach so klammheimlich unters Volk gebracht?",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Wenn die Versicherung keine Gewinne machen würde dann würde sie die Versicherung gar nicht anbieten.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Wie einfältig müssen doch manche echt sein.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Das SPON-Forum: So wollen wir debattieren Alle Rechte vorbehalten Vervielfältigung nur mit Genehmigung der SPIEGELnet GmbH Die Homepage wurde aktualisiert.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Bitte deaktivieren Sie Ihren Adblocker!,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Vielen Dank!,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,"? Bitte prüfen Sie, ob Sie ähnliche Erweiterungen, Do-not-Track-Funktionen oder den Inkognito-Modus aktiviert haben, die ebenfalls Werbung unterdrücken.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,? Hier finden Sie mehr Informationen .,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Sie haben einen anderen Browser?,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Verbraucherschützer sind alarmiert.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Sie kannte das schon.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Und einer ist immer hellgrün.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Zu Schuljahresbeginn werden in Baden-Württemberg an staatlichen und privaten Schulen von den Klassenlehrern Versicherungspolicen an die Schüler verteilt.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Die einen sind hellgrün, die anderen rosa.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Die Versicherung kostet nicht viel, nur einen Euro pro Schuljahr.",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,. Wie der Mutter aus Esslingen geht es Hunderttausenden Eltern in Baden-Württemberg.,2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL ONLINE,sentences,". Manche füllen auch eine der Zusatzversicherungen aus für Garderobe (ein Euro), Fahrrad (sechs Euro), Musikinstrumente (sechs Euro) und für Internatsschüler (sechs bis sieben Euro).",2.0
Baden-Württemberg: Lehrer verteilen Angebote für unnötige Zusatzversicherungen - SPIEGEL
```

kind regards

Tobias